# configuring nginx for static vuejs site

Tags: nginx, vue.js, server, web-deployment, centos7

I have been trying to configure my nginx vuejs static frontend. My site consistently returns a 500. I based my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file [this site](https://gist.github.com/szarapka/05ba804dfd1c10ad47bf).

When I go to the specified ip_address, the 500 screen is returned and returns specifically `500 Internal Server Error nginx/1.12.2`.

Why would it do this? I know that the root filepath is correct but it apparently can't seem to find it.

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  floating_ip_address;
    root         ~/frontendFolder;
    index        index.html

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }

    location @rewrites {
         rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The most recent logs are as follows:

```
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:39:59 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin-old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:40:00 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdminold/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:40:00 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin.old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:40:03 +0000] "GET /pma-old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:40:03 +0000] "GET /claroline/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:40:05 +0000] "GET /typo3/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:40:07 +0000] "GET /phpma/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:40:07 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:40:15 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:44:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7" "-"
ip - - [12/Sep/2018:16:47:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 595 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: What's in the log?

Comment: Which log? If I run service nginx status, then there are no errors, it has started and is active (running).

Answer (score 3):

i had the same issue with my **Vue project**, I'm 100% sure that my nginx server block is good.
*Here is an example:*

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;        charset utf-8;
root    /var/www/myapp/dist;
index   index.html;
#Always serve index.html for any request
location / {
    root /var/www/myapp/dist;
    try_files $uri  /index.html;
}
error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;
}
```

but, I get the error 500. also i assign the execution permission to **dist/** folder and nginx user ownership of file:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data ./dist/*
```

and

```
chmod 755 -R ./dist/*
```

[image: nginx 500 error on vue]

**SOLUTION**

-1 check the www-data user has the path/ file permission

```
root@root:# sudo -u www-data stat /home/myuser/public_html/
```

**OUTPUT:**

> sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is group writable sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is group
> writable   File: /home/efficonx/public_html/   Size: 4096
> Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory Device: fc01h/64513d
> Inode: 258318      Links: 4 Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (    0/
> root)   Gid: (    0/    root) Access: 2022-12-07 13:48:55.245310115
> +0000 Modify: 2022-12-06 13:13:40.187999036 +0000 Change: 2022-12-07 13:48:33.149826680 +0000 Birth: 2022-12-06 07:34:49.277257817 +0000

-2 if the www-data have no permission then assign him group/permission
in my case i add him to root user group

```
sudo adduser www-data root
```

and all DONE.

Answer (score 2):

Update the first line in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
```

to

```
user ubuntu;
```

Comment: Just had the same issue, this solved it for me after *days* of trying. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an nginx guru but we have a production server running nginx to serve a static Vue website and proxy API and WebSocket requests to a Butterfly Server .NET running on port 8200.

Anyways, this is our nginx config file, hope it helps...

```
server {
    listen                      80;
    listen          [::]:80;
    server_name                 my.mysite.com;
    root                        /opt/mysite/my;
    return 301 https://my.mysite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen          443 default_server ssl;
    server_name                 my.mysite.com;
    ssl_certificate     /opt/mysite/ssl/my_mysite_io.bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /opt/mysite/ssl/my_mysite_io.key;
    root                        /opt/mysite/my;
    client_max_body_size        128000000;

    # index
    index index.html;

    # $uri, index.html
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|ico)$ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        access_log off;
    }

    location /index.html {
        expires -1;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is anything in your config optional? Is the /api optional? My api is independent from my ui, so I omitted it? Trying to understand nginx better. I assumed it would work once I gave it the correct path but that was clearly naive.

Comment: Yes, both the /api and /ws location sections are only needed to proxy those type of requests to another server.  Remove those if you like.  I'm not an nginx guru either -- I was just sharing what we had working on our server.